# Read and write struct in C

Tags: c, file

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct student
{
        char fname[30];
        char sname[30];
        char tname[30];
        Faculty fac;
        int course;
        char group[10];
        int room;
        int bad;
} Student;
```

I read it from the file:

```
Database * dbOpen(char *fname)
{
        FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
        List *lst, *temp;
        Student *std;
        Database *db = malloc(sizeof(*db));

        if (!fp)
                return NULL;

        FileNameS = fname;

        std = malloc(sizeof(*std));
        if (!fread(std, sizeof(*std), 1, fp)) {
                db->head = db->tail = NULL;
                return db;
        }

        lst = malloc(sizeof(*lst));
        lst->s = std;
        lst->prev = NULL;
        db->head = lst;
        while (!feof(fp)) {
                fread(std, sizeof(*std), 1, fp); 
                temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
                temp->s = std;
                temp->prev = lst;
                lst->next = temp;
                lst = temp;
        }
        lst->next = NULL;
        db->tail = lst;

        fclose(fp);

        return db;
}
```

And I have a problem... At the last record i have a such file pointer:
`fp 0x10311448 {_ptr=0x00344b90 "НННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННН _ _iobuf *

`
And i read last record 2 times...

Save file code:

```
void * dbClose(Database *db)
{
        FILE *fp = fopen(FileNameS, "w+b");
        List *lst, *temp;

        lst = db->head;
        while(lst != NULL) {
                fwrite(lst->s, sizeof(*(lst->s)), 1, fp);
                temp = lst;
                lst = lst->next;
                free(temp);
        }
        free(db);
        fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: And this is one of many reasons I have come to like the STL containers.  It's easy to forget just how fun debugging list code can be.

Comment: The description of the problem you're having is not clear. Could you please elaborate? Also, I believe the last piece of code is duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of observed and seeming problems for you to consider:

(1) What if your file's length in bytes is not exactly a multiple of `sizeof(Student)`?  Then this code:

```
while (!feof(fp)) {
    fread(std, sizeof(*std), 1, fp);
    ...
```

could read a partial struct into the memory pointed to by `std`.  The contents of `std` would be partially filled and could leave an unterminated C string in memory.

You must check the return value of `fread()`.

(2) This a more important issue.  You are re-using the memory allocated and pointed to by `std`, although you store the pointer in each element of your linked list.

It seems that your intention would be to allocate new memory for each `Student` record.  In this case, you would call `malloc()` within the body of the loop which reads multiple records from the file.

This error depends on the file length, also -- the file must contain more than one record.

(3) You could reorganize your code so that the first record is also read during a loop iteration, to remove needlessly duplicated code.

(4) You might consider using `calloc()` to ensure that you have initialized all the records of `Student`.

Like so:

```
Database * dbOpen(char *fname)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
    List *lst, *temp;
    Student *std;
    Database *db = NULL;

    if (!fp)
            return db;

    FileNameS = fname;

    db = malloc(sizeof(*db));
    db->head = NULL;
    lst = NULL;
    while (!feof(fp)) {
            std = malloc(sizeof(*std));
            if (!fread(std, sizeof(*std), 1, fp))
            {
                free(std);
                fprintf(stderr, "Input file concludes in partial record.\n");
                break;
            }

            temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
            temp->s = std;
            temp->prev = lst;
            temp->next = NULL;

            if (lst == NULL)
                db->head = temp;
            else
                lst->next = temp;
            lst = temp;
    }
    assert(lst->next == NULL ); /* Now performed above by temp->next assignement. */
    db->tail = lst;

    fclose(fp);

    return db;
}
```

I didn't compile and test the above code, but it should be close to working.  Notice how a special case is added to either initialize `db->head` (first time through the loop, with *lst* equal *NULL*), otherwise the previous list element is linked to the newly added element (later iterations).  Of course we also should be checking the return values from `malloc()`, but that is left out for clarity here.

Comment: Point 1 shows a canonical example of why `while (feof(...))` is usually wrong.  In this case it should simply be `while (fread(...) == 1)`

Answer (score 1):

This stands out to me:

```
while (!feof(fp)) { 
            fread(std, sizeof(*std), 1, fp);  
            temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp)); 
            temp->s = std; 
            temp->prev = lst; 
            lst->next = temp; 
            lst = temp; 
        }
```

You should not use `feof()` as a loop condition; the end-of-file indicator is not set until *after* you attempt to read past the end of the file, so your loop will execute one too many times.  Restructure your loop to use the return value of `fread()`, and check against `feof()` only if `fread()` fails:

```
while (fread(std, sizeof *std, 1, fp) == 1)
{
  temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
  temp->s = std;
  ...
}
if (feof(fp)) 
  // handle end of file
else
  // handle other read error
```

Answer (score 0):

First pass without digging too deep yet, I'd say you've written pass the end of your record.  The output you show looks a lot like debug memory output that you would see trailing a malloc buffer.  Perhaps your database isn't aligned quite correctly?  Looking some more now...

Answer (score 0):

In this loop:

```
    while (!feof(fp)) {
            fread(std, sizeof(*std), 1, fp); 
            temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
            temp->s = std;
            temp->prev = lst;
            lst->next = temp;
            lst = temp;
    }
```

you are using the result of the `fread` without checking that it returned successfully.
You should check `feof(fp)` or the return value of `fread` before assuming the data was successfully read.